# Proving equivalence of Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am working on the following question concerning the axiom of choice and one of its many equivalences. Advice as to whether I am on the right track would be appreciated.
As a preface, I have looked at most of the other 'axiom of choice' posts on math.stackexchange already so referencing me to them may not help me a whole lot as I am asking this question $after$ having read those posts. In any case, I may have missed something in these posts so please do recommend a post if you think it will help me. Thank you very much for your time, in advance.

---

We show that the following statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice: For any set $A$, there is a function $F$ with $dom \ F = \bigcup A$ such that $x \in F(x) \in A$ for all $x \in \bigcup A$. Call this statement $S$.

To prove that $S$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice, we show that $S$ holds iff version 4 of the axiom of choice holds (p.151): Let $A$ be a set such that (a) each member of $A$ is a nonempty set, and (b) any two distinct members of $A$ are disjoint. Then there exists a set $C$ containing exactly one element from each member of $A$ (i.e., for each $B \in A$, the set $C \cap B$ is a singleton $\{x\}$ for some $x$. Call this version $S'$.

First, we show that $S \ \implies \ S'$. Assume that $S$ holds and that $A$ is a set such that each member is a nonempty set and any two members of $A$ are disjoint. Then, there is a function $f$ such that $dom \ f = \bigcup A$ and $\forall x \in \bigcup A$ ($x \in f(x) \in A$). We now have $dom \ f \subseteq ran \ f \in A$, and so  $ran \ f  \neq \emptyset$ by the definition of $A$. Further, we have $ran \ f \ \cap \ B = \{f(x)\}$, for some $x \in A$ and for any $B \in A$. So $ran \ f = C$, and $S'$ holds where $C \cap B$, for any $B \in A$ is a singleton.

Comment: Always lead with the question. People who want to help you would like to figure out quickly whether they can. Later, you can tell us why you are asking, if it's really important.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you have that $\operatorname{dom}(f)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(f)$. Note that $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$ means that $x\in X\in A$, and $F(x)\in A$. Therefore $\operatorname{dom}(f)\subseteq\bigcup A$ and $\operatorname{ran}(f)\subseteq A$.

So you can't quite use $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ to define $C$.

Instead, consider $A'=\{\{A\times X,x\}\mid x\in X\in A\}$, and apply $S$ to $A'$, you get a function which chooses for each $X\in A$ and each $x\in X$ a pair that exactly one element of it is an element of $X$, so you can cook up $C$ as wanted.

Comment: Asaf, thank you for your continuous help (you have answered many of my questions before).

However, I don't understand what 'X' (big X) is referring to. Can you please define it?

Comment: $X$ is just an element of $A$.

Comment: Okay but I am still confused. I don't understand how $x \in dom f$ entails that $x \in X \in A$ for any $X \in A$. I also don't understand why you have $dom f \subseteq \bigcup A$, when $dom f$ is simply equal to $\bigcup A$. I do however understand why it is false that $dom f \subseteq ran f$ and that I was wrong on this.

Comment: If $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\bigcup A$, then $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$ means $x\in\bigcup A$, which in turn means that for some $X\in A$, $x\in X$. You are correct about $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\bigcup A$, but the point I wrote it for is that the domain and range of $f$ are subsets of different sets, which can easily be disjoint. Therefore they cannot [necessarily] satisfy any inclusion relations between them. Consider the case where $A=\{\{x\}\}$, then $\bigcup A=\{x\}$ and $f(x)=\{x\}$, so the range of $f$ is $\{\{x\}\}$. Is $\{x\}\subseteq\{\{x\}\}$?

Comment: Okay, I think there was simply misunderstanding as to quantification as what you were stating is that if $x \in dom f = \bigcup A$ then $x \in X \in A$ for $some \ X \in A$.

Comment: Suppose we have $Y \in X \in A$ and also $Z \in Y \in A$ (and we will have $X \not \in Y$). E.g. $Z = 0, Y = 1, X = 2, A = 3$. Then $A'$ will contain $\{X,Y\}$ and also $\{Y,Z\}$. Perhaps $F(Y) = \{X,Y\}$ -- that will make the rest of the construction fail, won't it?  I couldn't see any way around this without tagging the "first" and "second" components of the unordered pair, something like $\{(0,X),(1,Y)\}$.

Comment: @Carl: I don't fully follow your comment. Is it aimed at me?

Comment: I am looking at the construction here, and comparing it to a construction I came up with. What I don't see is why, in this construction, if $F(X) = \{X,Y\}$, that ensures that we have $Y \in X$, because the pair $\{X,Y\} = \{Y,X\}$ might end up in $A'$ because $X \in Y \in A$. @Asaf

Comment: @Carl: Hmm, yes, it seems that I assume the elements of $A$ make an $\in$-antichain. This seems to be easily corrected by taking $\{A\times X,x\}$ though. Right? (Also, you don't have to ping me when you comment on my answers, I get notified either way.)

Comment: Yes, it can be corrected in various ways by marking one or both coordinates of the unordered pairs so it becomes clear which one is "supposed to be" the first coordinate and which is supposed to be the second coordinate.  [As for the pinging, there is also a benefit in knowing who was the intended recipient of a comment. In my conception of things, comments without pings can be seen as comments "to the reader", while comments with pings are clearly intended for a specific person.  This is the same as email lists, etc.: some posts are addressed to the general reader, others are replies. ] @Asaf

Comment: @Carl: [Yes, but you can just write Asaf: at the start of the comment, with the at-symbol, then it's immediately clear that I'm the intended reader, and no additional pings - which may be removed by the system - are needed.]

Comment: @Carl: Also, thanks for pointing out that delicate implicit assumption in my answer!

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila , I would like to confirm two things regarding your solution. 1) I think you use $\{A\times X,x\}$ instead of $\{X,x\}$ because there possibly exists $y \in Y \in A$ such that $y=X$. Thus when you use $\{A\times X,x\}$, you can prove $ A\times X \neq y$ for all $y \in \cup A, X \in A$. 2) Instead of your $A’$, may I use my $A'=\{(X,x)\mid x\in X\in A\}$ to get the desired set $C$?

Comment: @DungLe: There are many ways of solving most of these equivalence statements. Frankly, I'm a bit too busy nowadays to try and recreate my mind set from three and a half years ago. It could very well be that I've made a mistake there. Just ignore this answer, and try to prove the equivalence yourself. I'm sure that you can do it, you just lack of the belief in yourself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I now understand your proof, and found that, with $A'=\{\{(X,x),x\}\mid x\in X\in A\}$, it is impossible to prove  $(X,x) \neq y$ for all $y \in \cup A, X \in A$ (since $(X,x)$ is not related to $y$ in general).